# How to efficiently do multiple writes to a file

Tags: go, data-structures

I need to write multiple lines to a file in Go. Those lines will be generated by another method. So, to write into a file, I thought of doing as many writes to the file as the number of lines. But writing to a file is a costly operation. I am thinking of a very optimistic way of writing to the file. What could be the data structure I could use here?

Answer (score 2):

To amortize the cost of operating system file reads and writes, use the Go standard library [`bufio`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/)package.

---

Here's a Go benchmark to illustrate the point: `bufio` is much faster.

```
$ go test bufio_test.go -bench=.
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkBufioWrite-4    50     20887474 ns/op    6774811 B/op    147938 allocs/op
BenchmarkOSWrite-4        3    387543398 ns/op    6022413 B/op    104415 allocs/op
$
```

`bufio_test.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "testing"
)

func BenchmarkBufioWrite(b *testing.B) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        out, err := ioutil.TempFile(``, `StackOverflow`)
        if err != nil {
            b.Fatal(err)
        }
        outName := out.Name()
        w := bufio.NewWriter(out)
        for _, line := range benchLines {
            _, err := w.Write([]byte(line))
            if err != nil {
                b.Fatal(err)
            }
        }
        err = w.Flush()
        if err != nil {
            b.Fatal(err)
        }
        err = out.Close()
        if err != nil {
            b.Fatal(err)
        }
        os.Remove(outName)
    }
}

func BenchmarkOSWrite(b *testing.B) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        out, err := ioutil.TempFile(``, `StackOverflow`)
        if err != nil {
            b.Fatal(err)
        }
        outName := out.Name()
        w := out
        for _, line := range benchLines {
            _, err := w.Write([]byte(line))
            if err != nil {
                b.Fatal(err)
            }
        }
        err = out.Close()
        if err != nil {
            b.Fatal(err)
        }
        os.Remove(outName)
    }
}

var benchLines = func() []string {
    // The Complete Works of William Shakespeare by William Shakespeare
    // http://www.gutenberg.org/files/100/100-0.txt
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(`/home/peter/shakespeare.100-0.txt`)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return strings.Split(string(data), "\n")
}()
```

Comment: The only file operation here is writing to the file. The lines to be written will be string generated by me. Not reading anything from file. Still bufio helps?

Comment: @Shyam: See my revised answer. I have added a Go benchmark.